# Can't read from kafka by KafkaIO in beam

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-beam, confluent-cloud

I have written a very simpel pipeline in Apchea Beam as follow to read data from my kafka cluster on Confluent Cloud as follow:

```
        Pipeline pipeline = Pipeline.create(options);

        Map<String, Object> propertyBuilder = new HashMap();
        propertyBuilder.put("ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm", "https");
        propertyBuilder.put("sasl.mechanism","PLAIN");
        propertyBuilder.put("request.timeout.ms","20000");
        propertyBuilder.put("retry.backoff.ms","500");

        pipeline
            .apply(KafkaIO.<byte[], byte[]>readBytes()
               .withBootstrapServers("pkc-epgnk.us-central1.gcp.confluent.cloud:9092")
               .withTopic("gcp-ingestion-1")  
               .withKeyDeserializer(ByteArrayDeserializer.class)
               .withValueDeserializer(ByteArrayDeserializer.class)
               .updateConsumerProperties(propertyBuilder)             
               .withoutMetadata() // PCollection<KV<Long, String>>
            ) .apply(Values.<byte[]>create());
```

However, I get below excpetion when running above codes to read data from my kafka cluster

I run above on direct java runner, I am using beam 2.8,

I can read and produce messages to my kafka confluent cluster but not by above codes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you follow the stack trace it appears that the code tries to cast the timeout configuration property to `Integer`: https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/2e759fecf63d62d110f29265f9438128e3bdc8ab/sdks/java/io/kafka/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/kafka/KafkaUnboundedReader.java#L112

But instead it gets a string. My guess is that this is because you set it as string here: `propertyBuilder.put("request.timeout.ms","20000")`. I assume the correct thing would be to set it as `Integer`, e.g. like `propertyBuilder.put("request.timeout.ms", 20000)` (no quotes around the timeout value).

You also may have similar issues with other configuration properties (e.g. retry backoff), you need to double check the property types.